# Issue while setuping Guacamole with Database connection

Tags: mysql, tomcat, java, mariadb, connector

I installed a Guacamole 1.4.0 instance on a RHEL 8.5 server.

Now, I need to setup the LDAP extensions, but for that I first need to setup the database connection and it's at this moment that I have an issue.

I'm using **MariaDB 10.3.28**

The connector isn't working, and I'm getting the error:

```
13:27:05.645 [main] ERROR o.a.g.extension.ExtensionModule - Extension "guacamole-auth-jdbc-mysql-1.4.0.jar" could not be loaded: Extension "MySQL Authentication" is not compatible with this version of Guacamole.
```

I tried to use

- mariadb-java-client-2.7.5.jar
- mariadb-java-client-3.0.3.jar
- mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
- mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar

None of them is working, and I can't find anywhere on the documentation where it say exactly which version need to be use.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with Tomcat?  Or just Apache?

Comment: I didn't use apache on this installation, It was setup with tomcat from the start